# Maximum number of pointer in one variable

Tags: c++, pointers, size, max

In my project, there are one million inputs and I am supposed to take different numbers of inputs in order to compare sort/search algorithms. Everything was allright till I tried to take five hundread thousand inputs. Therefore, I have realized that I can't create five hundred thousand pointers to my class or even an integer type by using array. However, I can create five pointers with size of one hundred thousand. 
    
    
    If I didn't explain very well, just look these two codes;

```
int *ptr[500000]; // it crashes

int *ptr1[100000]; // it runs well
int *ptr2[100000];
int *ptr3[100000];
int *ptr4[100000];
int *ptr5[100000];
```

What is the reason of crashing? Is there a limiting or is it about memory? And of course, how can I fix it?

Comment: try allocating to the heap instead

Comment: `std::vector<int*> ptr(SIZE);`

Comment: Why do you need to store 500000 locations of variables? Why don't just read all values into an array and do thigns on it? That'll be much faster than storing 500000 different locations and read data from those pointers

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to allocate a 500,000-entry array on the stack. The stack is not really designed for holding large amounts of data like this. In your case, the stack just happens to be big enough to hold 100,000 entries (or even several different lots of 100,000 entries) but not 500,000 in a single block. If you overflow the stack, behaviour is undefined but a crash is likely.

You will get much better results by allocating your array on the heap instead.

```
int **ptr = malloc(500000*sizeof(int*));
```

Remember to check for a NULL return value from malloc, and free the memory when you're finished with it.

Comment: in regards to the stack allocation; my guess is that both snippets fail, just in different ways

Comment: "In your case, the stack just happens to be big enough to hold 100000 entries but not 500000." Still, it can apparently hold 5 times 100000? That's the really strange thing here. Or is it UB ?

Comment: @JBL That appears to be luck, depending on how the C runtime is actually allocating the chunks on the stack.

Comment: @JBL, e.g. there is no space for 500000 consecutive bytes, but enough space for 5 chunks of 100000 consecutive bytes, seems legit.

Comment: Any reason not to use `vector<int*>`?

Comment: @NeilKirk question is tagged C and C++

Comment: @GrahamBorland I am sorry I made mistake with writing tag 'c'. I am writing my program with c++ and malloc is not suggested in c++. Is there a way to increase the maximum stack size? Or should I still use malloc?

Comment: @FatihBilginer In c++ you should use `new` or even better here, an `std::vector`.

Comment: Are you sorting integers, and if so, 32 bit integers or 64 bit integers? If you are sorting integers, is there a reason for using arrays or vectors of pointers to those integers? It seems you could test one sort algorithm at a time, as long as you initialize the data with the same pseudo random data for each run.

Comment: Now that the OP has clarified it's strictly a C++ question, I'm happy for anyone to edit this to be a C++ answer with `std::vector` or whatever. Any volunteers?